# How to retrieve the data, "how many people think this review is helpful" from amazon?

Tags: r, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the data from amazon. the url is here.

http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Wireless-Marathon-3-year-Battery/product-reviews/B003TG75EG/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_summary?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=byRankDescending

It is a product review page. I find that the data is between these two tags as below

```
<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
395 of 405 people found the following review helpful
</div>
```

The problem is that other info are also contained between these two tags. Does anyone have some good idea to retrieve these data?

Thank you.

Comment: `?gsub` is probably the easiest place to start.

Comment: What do you actually want back as result? The whole string or just _395_? It is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a unclear, but I would guess you actually want to get back the *395*, not the whole text.

You can get back the element like so (which I think is a better solution as markup and class names can easily change, but the ID `recMHRL` will likely stay)

```
/div[@id = "revMHRL"]/div/div/span[contains(@class, "a-size-small")][contains(@class, "a-color-secondary")]
```

and extract the number you can do

```
tokenize(normalize-space(/div[@id = "revMHRL"]/div/div/span[contains(@class, "a-size-small")][contains(@class, "a-color-secondary")]/text()), "\s+")[1]
```

This removed leading and traling white spaces first and then tokenizes the strings based on whitespaces, returning back only the first element.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to extract from the first review.
Also, I assume you only have XPATH 1.0 functions and not XPATH 2, therefore no tokenize function available.

First, the expressions suggested so far rely too much on the structure of the page, that amazon changes frequently. That means the same can fail in few days. A better expression to select the node you want is

`//*[@id='revMH']/h3/following::node()[contains(text(),'people found the following review helpful')][1]`

because it's unlikely that amazon will change the text showed to user.

Once we have that, to extract the *395* you can use:

`substring-before(//*[@id='revMH']/h3/following::node()[contains(text(),'people found the following review helpful')][1]," of")`

In case you want *395 of 405* just use `substring-before(.....,' people')`, and then split the two numbers in your host language. 
You can even use `translate` to get a text like e.g., *395 / 405*, with

`translate(normalize-space(//div[@id = "revMHRL"]/div/div/span[contains(@class, "a-size-small")][contains(@class, "a-color-secondary")]/text()),"of",'/')`

Answer (score 0):

please try this xpath

```
//div[@class='a-section']/div[@class='a-row a-spacing-micro']/span[@class='a-size-small a-color-secondary']/text()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jonesy This does_ provide an answer to the question. I think you misjudged here during review.